# Changing from an excel spreadsheet to another always going to same cell ref

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, cells

can anyone help with hint of how to move from an excel spreadsheet by selecting another tab, and going to a predetermined cell ref?
For certain kinds of excel works, with business models for instance, I find always difficult navigating between spreadsheets, wondering around that sheet, then going back and forth to another, and the mouse cursor is on the last position I left it.
Maybe there a way (or a macro) to make sure that when I re-enter a spreadsheet the mouse cursor is ALWAYS on the same cell ref.
Thanks in advance.
André

Comment: Some ideas, 1) before exiting the file move to the cells you want to start back on. 2) protect sheet/unprotect cells, you will then only be able to tab to unprotected cells. 3) create a macro such that when a tab is selected the macro activates the cell you want to go to. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a simple hyperlink (even use the `HYPERLINK()` function for it) that leads to the tab and cell desired.

People even set up Tables of Contents using this.

And of course, one can use VBA, just as one can use VBA for almost anything.

The difficulty with hyperlinks is that you land in the cell, but if the cell was sin the center of the visible area for the sheet, that's where it'll be when you get there. Often one desires it be the upper left corner of the screen, that kind of thing. If so, you can set up a couple hyperlinks that you must click on to go to a cell that forces the desired cell into the desired position on the screen, then to go to that cell. But... who is going to do two clicks for you, right? That's a good time for VBA. Unless, of course, it's just for your own use, or just a shortterm, ad hoc local office thing.